# How to perform validation before delete in Django Tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I tried to overwrite obj_delete to perform pre-delete validation, to decide if delete should be performed based on submitted data and database data. This is my test code. I am not sure what is the right way to do it.

But, I could not figure it out. Please help with sample code.

```
class HelloAuthorization(Authorization):

  def delete_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
      # Try to decide if delete should be performed HERE. But it is not get called. 
      # Why??? HELP!!!!

      return True

  def obj_delete(self, request=None, **kwargs):
    try:
      obj = self.obj_get(request, **kwargs)

      # Try to decide if delete should be performed HERE. But it is not get called. 
      # Why??? HELP!!!!

   except ObjectDoesNotExist:
      raise NotFound('A model instance matching the '
                     'provided arguments could not be found.')
    obj.delete()


class HelloResource(ModelResource):
  class Meta(object):
    queryset = models.HelloModel.objects.all()
    allowed_methods = ('get', 'post', 'put', 'delete')
    resource_name = 'hello'
    authentication = Authentication()
    authorization = HelloAuthorization()
    filtering = {'name': constants.ALL,
                 'id': constants.ALL}

  def delete_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
      # Try to decide if delete should be performed HERE. But it is not get called. 
      # Why??? HELP!!!!

      return True

  def obj_delete(self, request=None, **kwargs):
    try:
      obj = self.obj_get(request, **kwargs)

      # Try to decide if delete should be performed HERE. But it is not get called.
      # Why??? HELP!!!!

    except django_exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist:
      raise NotFound('A model instance matching the '
                     'provided arguments could not be found.')
    obj.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code hasn't been tested but should work:

```
def obj_delete(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    _my_object = bundle.obj
    # perform validation
    if True: # validated
        super(AccountsResource, self).obj_delete(bundle, **kwargs)
    else:
        # TODO
        # do my thing here
        pass
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks

### Edit:

> If you are sending the request on `/api/v1/hello/`, `obj_delete` won't get called, for that to get called you need to send a DELETE request on `/api/v1/hello/1/`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But, it's not getting called, including delete_detail(). This problem puzzled me for long time. I added obj_delete to HelloResource class, just like delete_details(). I am not sure what is missing. Can you help?

Comment: can you please also include the request you are sending? Thanks

Comment: Not sure what do you mean 'include request'? Do you mean complete code? My question is why the function obj_delete() is not getting called.

Comment: I found  def obj_delete_list(self, bundle, **kwargs) is getting called, but obj_delete(self, bundle, **kwargs) is not getting called.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was wondering, and asked you to include the request.. If you are sending the request on `/api/v1/hello/`,  `obj_delete` won't get called, for that to get called you need to send a DELETE request on `/api/v1/hello/1/`.